# Get dates difference in minutes with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with a field called `end_date` of type `DATETIME` which stores a UTC date. I want to get the difference in minutes between `NOW()` and the `end_date` value. I alredy found a lot of questions and answers here on stackoverflow to do this, some uses `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` which from what I understand takes the input value and converts it to UTC (so I can't use it because my date is alredy UTC) and other that suggests to use `TIME_TO_SEC` and divide by `60`. This is what I picked up:

```
INTERVAL (TIME_TO_SEC(UTC_TIMESTAMP()) - TIME_TO_SEC(end_date)) / 60 MINUTE
```

It works fine until the current day is different from the `end_date`'s day. At that point, the result of the subtraction is negative and when I use this code inside a `DATE_ADD` function it outputs the wrong result. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
INTERVAL (TO_SECONDS(UTC_TIMESTAMP()) - TO_SECONDS(end_date)) / 60 MINUTE
```

Comment: I can't find TO_SECONDS in the MySQL docs. By the way, I can't use NOW because as I alredy said in my question the stored date is in UTC while NOW returns the current date in the server's timezone

Comment: check here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-seconds , I edit my answer to set back UTC_TIMESTAMP()

Answer (score 2):

Try `ABS`

```
INTERVAL (ABS( TIME_TO_SEC(UTC_TIMESTAMP()) - TIME_TO_SEC(end_date))) / 60 MINUTE
```

Or, if you always want a *positive* difference, then on `end_date` check if it is later than `now` or `utc_timestamp`. If it is later replace it with `now` and the difference would be `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL's [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function:

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, CURRENT_TIME, end_date)
FROM   my_table
```

However, note that for this application you should really use MySQL's `TIMESTAMP` data type (which automatically converts between the session's [`time_zone`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone) and UTC for storage) instead of `DATETIME` (which performs no timezone conversion, but just stores the value as if one took a photograph of a calendar & clock).  Consequently, if your session's `time_zone` is anything other than UTC, with your current `DATETIME` field you will suffer errors arising from a lack of timezone conversion—one would have to explicitly adjust for such differences, e.g. using [`CONVERT_TZ()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz).

See [MySQL Server Time Zone Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/time-zone-support.html) for more information.

Comment: I'm storing the value as a datetime because I always convert to and from UTC inside my PHP application, so there is no need to do conversions in the database as I'm always sure that the values are stored in UTC

Comment: @Stefano: Fair enough, but be sure to set the session's `time_zone` to UTC before performing this operation (or else the value used for `CURRENT_TIME` will be in a different timezone and MySQL will not convert `end_date` to be compatible).

Comment: this is why I used UTC_TIMESTAMP instead of NOW for example :D

Comment: look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-timestamp, it returns a string formatted as a datetime field